# Using mysqli_query in the if construct

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic question, just starting to dive into PHP and Mysql.

There seems to be an error in this construct, can anyone help me?

Thanks!
K.

```
if ($password = mysqli_query ("SELECT password FROM users WHERE firstname = '$username'")) {

    echo "password success!";

     }
         else {
          echo "Password fail!";
}
```

Comment: Why does there seem to be an error?  What do you expect to happen?  What actually happens?  `if ($password = mysqli_query)` should probably be `if ($password == mysqli_query)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  mysqli you have to store your **db_connection** into a variable and have to pass in every query. Below is the complete path what you have to follow:

1. Create connection with database by using host_name, user_name, password,db_name. And store connection into a variable.
2. You can run any query by passing connection variable.

below code is:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if ($password = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT password FROM users WHERE firstname = '$username'")) {
    echo "password success!";
}
else {
    echo "Password fail!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Step one when you have a question, refer to the manual.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Now are you using the object oriented style or procedural? You are missing the link in either approach.

Once you resolve that you have the issue that the function doesn't return a string.

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

So with that you'll either get false on an error or a `mysqli_result` object. To parse through the object use `fetch`; http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php.

But first you should be using prepared statements which will greatly reduce your chances of being SQL injected; http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.

After that you should pass the password in with your query because you can just have mysql evaluate that the password and username match up then if you get a returned result you know the data is valid.

Additional note: you shouldn't store passwords in plain text, if you are.

Also the `=` assigns a value. To compare two values you need to use `==` or `===`. For a longer write up see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your connection details are stored in a variable $db
Firstly, you need to provide mysqli_query with the database connection resource in procedural mode.

```
$password = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT password FROM users WHERE firstname = '$username'");
```

Comment: It is not a `mysql` error it is a PHP implementation error.

Comment: Yes, i saw it. The connection details has to be passed through the first argument in procedural mode.

Comment: Amongst other issues such as that that function doesnt return a string, `=` doesnt compare, etc..

Comment: I simply assumed OP intended to compare it in the if clause.

Comment: Yea, `=` doesn't compare, it assigns..

Comment: Since i cannot comment on other answers, you should edit your answer to let him know about display_errors. If it was on, he'd see the error that mysqli_query would return